# Misdirected Request happening on Apple devices

Tags: ios, macos, http, http-status-code-421

An annoying and persistent issue that I've been facing is a "**Misdirected Request Error The client needs a new connection for this request as the requested host name does not match the Server Name Indication (SNI) in use for this connection**" when carrying out an AJAX request from my front end to the back end. CORS origin has been taken care of. The weird thing is that this issue only occurs with Apple devices (iPhone/Mac Book) on Safari and Chrome. Other Android and Windows devices work seamlessly. I tried purchasing an additional dedicated SSL certificate to my domain which includes two subdomains (the frontend and backend) from GoDaddy.

Any other tips/solutions please?

Answer (score 0):

Issuing a separate SSL certificate for the two sub-domains did the trick. Make sure that the two sub-domains are not grouped under the same certificate.